# In simple linear regression, why the covariance between y bar and beta1 hat is zero?

Tags: regression, covariance

In simple linear regression, where the model

$$\mathbb{E}(y) = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x$$

is estimated using least squares (and the errors are assumed iid of mean $0$), why is the covariance between the mean response $\bar{y}$ and the estimated slope $\hat{\beta_1}$ equal to zero?

Comment: I'm sorry, but it is in no way clear what beta 1 hat is! Can you elaborate on the model in question?